# c++,operator < がどこで使われてるか知りたい

Tags: c++

参考書は明解C++中級の本324ページです。
テンプレート関数について勉強していますがコード
operator > 演算子がどこでどのように使われているかがわかりません、
コメントにして実行してみた結果sort()のあたりで比較できないとのエラーが出たので
わかったのですがどのような原因でエラー出たのでしょうか？

```
 ///////////////////////テンプレート関数のIntTwin.cpp////////////////////////
            #ifndef ___class_Twin
        #define ___class_Twin
        #include <ostream>
        #include <utility>
        #include <algorithm>

        template<class type>class Twin {
        private:
            type v1;
            type v2;

        public:

            /*コンストラクタ*/
            Twin(const type& f = type(),const type& s = type()) :  v1(f),v2(s) { }

            /*コピーコンストラクタ*/
        //  Twin(const Twin<type>& t) : v1(t,first()),v2(t.second()){ }

            type first()const {
                return v1;
            }

            type& first() {
                return v1;
            }

            type second()const {
                return v2;
            }

            type& second() {
                return v2;
            }


            void set(const type& f, const type& s) {
                v1 = f;
                v2 = s;
            }

            type min()const {
                return v1 < v2 ? v1 : v2;
            }

            bool ascending()const {
                return v1 < v2;
            }

            void sort() {
                if ( (v1 < v2) != true ) {
                    std::swap(v1,v2);
                }
            }
        };


        /*挿入子*/
        template<class type> inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Twin<type>& t) {
            std::cout << "debug_Twin<type> ";
            return os << "[" << t.first() << "," << t.second() << "]";
        }



        #endif;



 ////////////////////////////main.cpp/////////////////////////////////////

            #include "conio.h"
        #include <new>
        #include <string>
        #include <iostream>
        #include "IntTwin.h"
        using namespace std;


        template<> inline ostream&  operator << (ostream& os, const 
          Twin<string>& st)
        {
            cout << "debug_Twin<string>";
            return os << "[\"" << st.first() << "\""",""\""<< st.second() << 
            "\"]";
        }

        template <class type> bool operator < (const Twin<type>& a, const nTwin<type>& b)
        {

            if ( a.first() < b.first() ) {
                return true;
            }
            else if ( !(b.first() < a.first()) && (a.second() < b.second()) ) {
                return true;//false
            }

            return false;//true
        }

    //////////////////////////main関数//////////////////////////

        int main() {

            Twin< Twin<int> > t1(  Twin<int>(36, 57), Twin<int>(23, 48)  );
            cout << "t1 = " << t1 << "\n";

            Twin< Twin<string > > t2( Twin<string>("ABC","XYZ"),Twin<string>("ABC", "ZZZ") );
            cout << "t2 = " << t2 << "\n";

            cout << "t2の値を変更しています\n";
            cout << "新しい第1値の第1値:"; cin >> t2.first().first();
            cout << "新しい第1値の第2値:"; cin >> t2.first().second();
            cout << "新しい第2値の第1値:"; cin >> t2.first().first();
            cout << "新しい第2値の第1値:"; cin >> t2.first().second();


            if (!t2.ascending()) {
                cout << "第一値＜第二値が成立しませんのでソートします。\n";
                t2.sort();              // 第一値 < 第二値となるようにソート
                cout << "t2は" << t2 << "に変更されました。\n";
            }



            _getch();
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: タイトルは `operator<` 本文は `operator>` になっていてタイトルが間違っているようです。オイラが修正してもいいですしご自分で編集してもよいですが、直していただけますか？

Comment: 再度参考書を確認しましたがoperator < になっているのですが、参考書が間違えているのでしょうか？

Comment: `template <class type> bool operator < (const Twin<type>& a, const nTwin<type>& b)` このメソッドがどこで使われているのか、という質問ですか?

Comment: というか、質問内容、変わりました?

Comment: はい、自分の勘違いしていた部分があったので修正しました。template <class type> bool operator < (const Twin<type>& a, const nTwin<type>& b) このメソッドがどこで使われているのかを知りたいので教えていただきたいです。

Comment: @beginner 質問内容が大きく変わる場合には別質問として投稿し直すことを検討してください。既に回答が付いた状態ですが、元々の質問文を想定しているはずなので食い違いが出てしまいます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下の部分でしょうか。

```
(106行目付近)Twin< Twin<int> > t1(  Twin<int>(36, 57), Twin<int>(23, 48)  );
```

これは、「operator >」ではなくテンプレート引数の閉じカッコです。

```
(読み替え)Twin<Twin<int>>     t1(Twin<int>(36, 57), Twin<int>(23, 48));
```

ですね。
ただし、こう書くとコンパイラの言語規格の対応状況によっては「>>」の部分が
まさに「operator >>」と誤って解釈される場合があるため、スペースを入れていると思われます。

Comment: 見落としてました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>        Twin< Twin<int> > t1(  Twin<int>(36, 57), Twin<int>(23, 48)  );
> ```

の行のことなら、この行で `operator>` は呼ばれていません。

`Twin< Twin<int> > t1;` をわかりやすく書き直すと

```
typedef Twin<int> twin_int_type;
Twin< twin_int_type > t1;
```

さて `Twin<int>` に別名 `twin_int_type` をつけたわけですが、ここで

- 「`Twin<int>` のコンストラクタは `int` ２つを引数にとる」
- 「`Twin<twin_int_type>` のコンストラクタは `twin_int_type` ２つを引数にとる」

ということは理解できますか？（ここが `template` の基礎っす）

`Twin<int>(36, 57)` は無名な `Twin<int>` すなわち `twin_int_type` オブジェクトを１つ生成しています。
`Twin<int>(23, 48)` も同様。

`t1` は `twin_int_type` ２つを引数にとるコンストラクタで初期化される必要があり、その引数が先ほどの２つの無名オブジェクトなわけです。

Comment: イメージは、twin< twin<int>,twin<int> >という意味でのしょうか？、またoperator <　はどこで利用しているのでしょうか？